# Play MediaElement sound without interrupting Zune music

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, xna

I've added sound effects to some events in my Windows Phone app using `MediaElement`. When these sounds play, the background music playing from other apps, like Zune, gets paused. Is it possible to overcome this?

I read somewhere that it can be achieved using XNA; but since I'm developing on my Windows 8 machine, I can't use XNA.

Answer (score 1):

Even when developing on Windows 8 you can use XNA libraries in your Windows Phone apps. You should probably use SoundEffect and SoundEffectInstance for playing sound, the only problem is you need to have the sounds in wav form as a part of your project, not mp3 or files stored in MediaLibrary, as far as I know.
[Difference between SoundEffect and SoundEffectInstance classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499093/difference-between-soundeffect-and-soundeffectinstance-classes)

Comment: I'm not able to add a reference to XNA

Comment: Why not? There is no issue in referencing Microsoft.Xna.Framework in your Windows Phone 7 project.

Comment: Did you try referencing it on Windows 8? It doesn't work. I can't even compile other projects which reference XNA on Windows 8.

Comment: If you're referring to Windows PHONE 8, yes you can. Windows 8 is another story...and it would be great if MSFT unified the audio code for both platforms, esp. for background audio.